# Point me to a Rails 4 example with Facebook canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-canvas

I only find examples of old Rails usage of the Facebook canvas app.
Especially with the latest changes Facebook made to the API's.

I am a little bit stuck with that. Does anyone now a gem + example or any other information how to use it properly in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully made it running with [Koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala). It provides you special method for parsing signed requests, so you can easily implement fetching data.

`Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('someapp','your_secret).parse_signed_request(params[:signed_request])`

Find more info & usage here: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth

You may also need to enable iframe for your controllers which can be done like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :allow_iframe

  private

  def allow_iframe
    response.headers.except! 'X-Frame-Options'
  end
end
```

Comment: Any simple sample that you can provide.

Comment: do you need to set the allow_iframe in every controller?

Comment: @GeertVanLaethem You could place it in ApplicationController, since all other controllers extend from the ApplicationController.